# View domain code values from ArcMap attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, domains

In the attribute table of a feature class in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1:

Is there a way to view data as the domain codes, rather than the domain descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [How To: Display coded value domains and subtype codes instead of descriptions](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012200) from Esri that describes showing the codes in the attribute table instead of the domain text descriptions.

[image: domain descriptions]

becomes

[image: domain codes]

Try:

*Customize > ArcMap Options > Tables*

Then, uncheck the '*Display coded value domain and subtype descriptions*' option.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the attribute table there is an option button at the top left of the table, in the "display" option (not sure it's named exactly like that) you should find a tick box to choose to display code or description of domain.